# How do I escape a table name or column name in SQL? esc_sql doesn't do this

Tags: sql, escaping

If you want to escape string values in an SQL query, you can use WordPress's [`esc_sql`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_sql/) function:

```
<?php

$wpdb->get_var( "SELECT * FROM something WHERE foo = '" . esc_sql( $foo ) . "'" );
```

You can also use the much more convenient [`prepare`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) function like this:

```
<?php

$wpdb>-get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM something WHERE foo = %s",
        $foo
    )
);
```

However, `esc_sql` is not suitable for escaping table names or column names, (only string values). And there is no way to use `prepare` for escaping table names or column names.

How can I escape `$foo` and `$bar` properly in this example SQL query?

```
SELECT * FROM $foo WHERE $bar = "example";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find a function shipped with WordPress that does this, so I created my own:

```
 function esc_sql_name( $name ) {
     return str_replace( "`", "``", $name );
 }
```

You can use it like this:

```
 $escaped_name = esc_sql_name( $column_name );

 $sql = $wpdb->prepare(
       "SELECT * FROM example WHERE `$escaped_name` = %s",
       $foobar
 );
```

### Reference:

- [MySQL documentation on identifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)

Comment: Thank you, myself from the past! I'm glad this showed up in my Google search. I would give you an upvote if you weren't me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `sanitize_key`

See the developer docs here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_key/

Note: it does perform a strtolower as WordPress Core Standards do require lowercase column names.